# How do I make an array of gps coordinates over land?

Tags: python, gps, matplotlib-basemap, astronomy

I am writing a python algorithm, which optimizes telescope positions for a radio interferometers, and for this i need an array of gps coordinates for possible positions to choose from. For now I have been using a big grid covering the an area of interest (see image).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Xtd.png)

However, the problem is that I would like to avoid the positions over water/oceans and only have a grid of evenly spaced coordinates over land. Any ideas of how I can achieve this? I know there is data for similar stuff here:

https://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/
https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html

The code I have below works fine and produces a grid over the globe just fine. I am just looking for advice on the above mentioned goal:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as rand
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

upper_lat = 70
lower_lat = -70
upper_lon = 140
lower_lon = -140

size = 100


#initializing which gps coordinates to start at 
La = lower_lat
Lo = lower_lon

#array to store coordinate
sites_gps = np.zeros((size*size,2))

f=0
for j in range(0,size):
    Lo=lower_lon
    for k in range(0,size):
        sites_gps[f] = La, Lo
        Lo+=(upper_lon+abs(lower_lon))/size
        f+=1
    La+=(upper_lat+abs(lower_lat))/(size)
```

Comment: Probably you need to go more in GIS direction. You will find shapefile of landmass, and you can use e.g. in Python https://shapely.readthedocs.io (or other libraries). I'm sure one of that libraries had an example with landmass.

Comment: My recommendation is to use an existing tool for generating the grids. Some time ago, I used Uber H3 hexagonal system: https://eng.uber.com/h3/. Or - in line with @GiacomoCatenazzi's comment - use a GIS tool; I have a good experience with PostGis (a GIS extension for PostgreSQL) and namely whit function: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SquareGrid.html

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).